# How to modify tslint rules

Tags: angular, rules, tslint

I want to set indent implicitly when I  do `ng new` to create a new application. So whenever a new application will be generated it will come with the new rule

```
"indent": [
    true,
    "tabs"
],
```

it should be applicable to all angular applications generated using `ng new`

Comment: I edited and added more description! please verify its what you are looking for

Comment: It is what I want to do.